# How can I download fIles

Tags: laravel, file, download

I created a page where I can upload files to "/storage/app/public/uploads". I have a download button, which works fine on my XAMPP test environment. As I uploaded the project to the server, I still can upload files. They also go to the same directory "/storage/app/public/uploads". But when I want to download them, the download-path is /storage/uploads/ and I get a 404 error. But this is also on my XAMPP.
in my /config/filesystems.php i have
'disks' => [

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

 'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
 ],
```

]

I have no clue, what's wrong, because on my XAMPP it's fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

example can you create a new controller for example,

```
<a hrfe="{{route('downloadfile1')}}">download</a>

public function downloadfile1(){

$file=public_path()."/file1.pdf";

 $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            );

 return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan storage:link` on server to fix it.